# How do I get api data using axios and proxy?

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm trying to get some simple data from an api via axios and vuejs.

```
axios.get('https://www.coinspot.com.au/pubapi/v2/latest')
.then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        console.log(response.status);
        console.log(response.statusText);
        console.log(response.headers);
        console.log(response.config);
 });
```

I get the following error:

GET http://localhost:8080/pubapi/v2/latest 404 (Not Found)

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404 at createError (createError.js?2d83:16) at settle (settle.js?467f:17) at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:62)
```

I can get this data to return in postman without anything special. How do I get this data to return without cors or 404 errors in my vuejs app?

Answer (score -1):

try using this

```
   axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'https://www.coinspot.com.au/pubapi/v2/latest',
        }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        console.log(response.status);
        console.log(response.statusText);
        console.log(response.headers);
        console.log(response.config);
 });
```